# How to deploy a directory and its content to the root instead of bin when publishing an ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a VS2010 Asp.Net project (Asp.Net Application, not a website) and I want to deploy a directory containing some text files to the root (using the Build->Publish VS2010 menu option)

If I set the "Copy to output directory" to "Always" or "Copy if newer" these files are copied to `/bin/Files` and I want them to be placed in `/Files`

Is there a way to do that using only Visual Studio 2010? How do I do that?

Comment: Where are they in the project itself?  If the project has a `/Files/` folder with some files in it then it should be treated like any other folder in the web application.  You shouldn't even need to specify the copy settings, they'd just be part of the website.

Comment: The directory is in the project's root. I don't know why is it deployed to the /bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the items in the directory, ensure that the Build Action is set to "Content".

Answer (score 0):

To get it working, select the file and open properties window. Set **Copy To Output Directory** to "Do not copy" and set the **Build Action** to "Content"